# clicking the parent div and children div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to implement something like this:

[image]

If the user clicked that specific link, a div will cover everything, clicking anywhere the grey area will close.

Here is how i implemented it:

```
<div id="cover" style="width:100%;height:100%;background-color:rgba(109,109,109,0.8);z-index:3; position:absolute; top:0px;left:0px;">
<div class="contactinfo">
</div>
</div>
```

It will be hidden at first by:

```
var $cover = $('#cover');
$cover.hide();
```

and it is controlled by:

```
$('.contact').click(function(){
$cover.show();
});

$cover.click(function(){
$cover.hide();
});
```

But the problem is that it still closes after i click the white area(inner div), i dont want it to close. What should i do? It should only close if the grey area is clicked.

this is my css for the inner div:

```
.contactinfo{

margin-top:200px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-bottom:auto;
margin-right:auto;
border:solid;
height:300px;
width:300px;
border-radius:25px;
background-image:Url('https://www.kiwiconferencing.co.nz/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Grey-Background-43.jpg');

}
```

Comment: Can you post a codepen?

Comment: uhmmm my code is kinda messy rn but let me try

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to compare, whether the clicked item is your `$cover` item.

```
$cover.on('click', function(e){
    if( e.target != this ) {
       //The clicked item is your inner div 
       return;
    }
    //Your clicked item is your $cover div
    $cover.hide();
});
```

Comment: I see, so if i click anything inside the parent div, it will also be treated as clicking the parent div itself?

Comment: @CarlosMiguelColanta Yes, apparently that's what is called as bubbling. If a click handler is not given for an element it will bubble upto it's parent to which the click handler is attached.

Comment: @CarlosMiguelColanta  Please consider doing a +1 if it helped you :)

Comment: Hmm are there other alternatives on stopping bubbling? I tried giving a click handler on my `contactinfo` but it didn't override the parent's.

Comment: @CarlosMiguelColanta why don't you just put the contactinfo div outside the cover div? That way it'll never bubble.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7qhj8y2r/1/)

**JS**

```
var $link = $(".contact");
var $cover = $('#cover');
var $contactinfo = $('.contactinfo');

$cover.hide();


$link.click(function(){
$cover.show();
});

$cover.click(function(){
$cover.hide();
});


$contactinfo.click(function(e) {
    ruturn false
});
```

Comment: @Nilesh Mahajan , @Carlos Miguel Colanta : Writing `return false` in place of `e.stopPropagation();` also does the same thing.

Comment: @Yogita088 Thanks for your suggestions. I have updated my answer please have a look.

Comment: @Salketer Thanks for your suggestions. I have updated my answer please have a look.

Comment: returning false will also preventDefault, not just stop propagation... @NileshMahajan next time, please update your answer, not fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because the click event bubbles up the DOM. So in the event you have to make sure that the user clicked on the same element that is listening to the event like so:

```
$cover.click(function(event){
    if(event.target == this){
        $cover.hide();
    }
});
```

Read about event bubbling and [event.target](https://api.jquery.com/event.target/)

Answer (score -1):

```
$('body').on('click','.greyarea',function(evt){
     Var target = evt.target || evt.srcElement
      Var isMouseClickedInsideGreyArea =           $(target).closest(this).length
      If(isMouseClickedInsideGreyArea){
           /*stay open */}else{/*close*/}})
```